# how to convert source type 'System.Nullable<bool>' to target type 'bool'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, xaml

Maybe this is a simple question, but I can't find the answer. Using XAML I have this code:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="3" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbIsInheriting"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" Margin="0,4,0,0" />
```

so in `.cs` file I need to get value of this Checkbox:
so I have:

```
res.IsInheriting = tbIsInheriting.IsChecked;
```

but this is a mistake            (cannot convert source type 'System.Nullable' to target type 'bool').

Comment: It depends on what you want to do if the checkbox is in the "indeterminate" state.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
tblsInheriting.IsChecked.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 9):

[`CheckBox.IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx) returns a `bool?` because it can be a three-way checkbox. If your checkbox is *never* three-way, I would personally use:

```
res.IsInheriting = tblsInheriting.IsChecked.Value;
```

That will throw an exception if somehow your check box has become three-way without you expecting it, and is in the indeterminate state.

Otherwise, if it *might* be three-way, I would use:

```
res.IsInheriting = tblsInheriting.IsChecked ?? defaultValue;
```

where `defaultValue` would probably be `true` or `false` depending on how you want the "indeterminate" state to be translated.

Comment: `??` is definitely the way to go. Another option is to write an extension method for `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (tbIsInheriting.IsChecked.HasValue == true)
     res.IsInheriting = tbIsInheriting.IsChecked.Value;
```